# Best way to extract and use data from a server database?

Tags: java, sql, database, web, extract

I have been tasked for an internship to retrieve data from the company's database and make a webapp displaying stats and graphs about it.

So far since my the langage I know the most is Java, I was thinking of extracting the SQL tables into .CSV files that I'd exploit to make the stats. 
But is there another more efficient way to do it that i'm missing ? Would another langage make the situation easier aswell ?

Comment: To do your stats in JAVA or in the DB (SQL) ? Since you need to show that in a webapp, you will need to read the CSV again so this won't be efficient or easy to manage.

Comment: For the web app part, Spring Boot will make your life easier, since you have Java background.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract it from the database directly.

Depending on the kind of data you can use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) or any other graph tool that displays it in the browser.